# Bind9 Configuration for domain name by duckdns

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, dns, bind

I am trying to test out some server stuffs on my debian virtualbox on a windows host. I have configured it to bridged network. And also was able to get duckdns free domain for testing and I can get letsencrypt ssl certificate  using dns challenge for duckdns domains. Now, the problem I have is in case if I want to make some records such as mx to test mail server setup I am not able to make them from duckdns. I found bind9 as a good option to manage dns for homelab network. So, I thought of using it. But I am not sure how the configurations and setup should be for this.

It would be great if someone could assist me on this...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your own DNS server with DuckDNS – the service does not delegate the subdomain to you; it only directly points to IP addresses. (That is, DuckDNS only publishes A/AAAA records for you but not NS records.)

For Bind9 to work, you'll need to either:

- find another free DNS service that would *delegate* the subdomain (NS records);
- or buy a "normal" domain from a registrar (as those almost universally have the option to be delegated to custom servers);
- or keep your setup completely internal, which allows you to use made-up domains (such as the officially reserved `.home.arpa` or fake TLDs such as `.zak`).

The last option is fairly common (that's how many home routers provide .lan DNS) and will work as long as your LAN hosts are configured either to use the Bind9 server directly (fortunately it can act as a resolver and an authoritative server at the same time), or to use a resolver that's been manually configured to recognize your `.whatever` zone (e.g. "server=" in dnsmasq or "stub-zone" in Unbound).

Comment: I don't have problem with using made up domains. But the problem is. I can't issue trusted ssl certs.